# Add checkbox in UltraGrid

Tags: ultrawingrid

How to dynamically add checkbox in infragistics UltraGrid

Answer (score 4):

Just make sure that the data-type of the column you are binding is of type bool. It will automatically create checkbox for that column.

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
 //get the data from db
 var ds = GetDataFromDatabase();

  ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Check", typeof(bool)); //this will create checkbox col

  foreach(Datarow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
  {
      row["Check"] = true; // make all rows checked just to see it works

  }


  DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView; //set it as a dataview

  ultraGrid1.DataSource = dv; //set the dataview as the datasource for your grid
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the column data type is `bool` (True/False or 0/1) then set:

```
grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["column_name"].Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.CheckBox;
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

While binding data to the grid, you can call the collection of a datatable through the query below:

"Select Convert(bit,0) as IsChecked, [OTHER_COLUMNS] from [TABLE_NAME]"

This will return a datatable with a first column of checkboxes.

Bind it with your grid using datasource.